# Grails 3 configuring CORS for multiple mappings in application.yml

Tags: grails, cors

I've tried following the official documentation guide here http://docs.grails.org/3.3.11/guide/single.html#cors but strangely I found that only the first mapping will ever get applied.

Their example:

```
grails:
    cors:
        enabled: true
        mappings:
            /api/**: inherit
```

What I assumed would work but doesn't (only the first mapping gets applied):

```
    grails:
        cors:
            enabled: true
            mappings:
                /api/**: inherit
                /api2/**: inherit
                ..
```

I must be missing something really simple as I was surprised to find no documentation or questions for multiple mappings like this. Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah that kind of killed me too. We solved this in the BeAPI Grails Plugin (which I maintain) by adding the mappings to the beapi_api.yml config file:

```
corsInterceptor:
    includeEnvironments: ['development','test','production']
    excludeEnvironments: []
    networkGroups:
        open: ['http://localhost','http://localhost:8080','http://127.0.0.1','http://test.nosegrind.net','http://test.nosegrind.net:8080']
        public: ['http://localhost','http://localhost:8080','http://127.0.0.1','http://test.nosegrind.net','http://test.nosegrind.net:8080']
        private: ['http://localhost','http://localhost:8080','http://127.0.0.1','http://test.nosegrind.net','http://test.nosegrind.net:8080']
```

Every request is checked to see what 'networkGroup' it belongs to (which is declared in the same config file):

```
networkGroups: ['open','public','private']
networkRoles:
    open: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_ANONYMOUS','ROLE_USER']
    public: ['ROLE_ADMIN','ROLE_USER']
    private: ['ROLE_ADMIN']
```

This allows GROUP/ROLE checking along with FQDN/IP checking on the frontend when doing a CORS check.

So all you have to do is add your FQDN/IP to the appropriate 'corsInterceptor.networkGroup'

Comment: This may seem convoluted but what it is doing is that it allows 'ROLE_GROUPS' such as 'ADMINISTRATORS' to close off what IP's/FQDNS can call the backend API's; this can make certain API endpoint strcitly internal or be on a closed VPN, etc. meeting the demands of larger networks.